# Calculating VRMS and HRMS from NMEA data?

Tags: gps, nmea

I am trying to write code to parse the NMEA strings coming from survey-grade RTK/GNSS receivers. The requirements I have are to calculate the 3DRMS (distance RMS at 97.5% probability), VRMS (vertical RMS) and HRMS (horizontal RMS) values (amongst others).

Going by [this article](http://www.radio-electronics.com/info/satellite/gps/accuracy-errors-precision.php), I've been able to find a formula to derive the 3DRMS value from the [GST NMEA message](http://www.trimble.com/OEM_ReceiverHelp/V4.44/en/NMEA-0183messages_GST.html):

In pseudocode: `3DRMS = 3 * Math.sqrt(Math.pow(dx,2) + Math.pow(dy,2))`

where `dx` is Latitude error and `dy` is Longitude error.

So, for example, if the GST message string is:

```
$GPGST,172814.0,0.006,0.023,0.020,273.6,0.023,0.020,0.031*6A
```

Then:

```
3DRMS = 3 * Math.sqrt(Math.pow(0.023,2) + Math.pow(0.020,2)) = 0.091
```

However, I'm struggling to find a definition or formula to calculate the VRMS and HRMS values, and therefore which NMEA strings I need to parse to calulate them.

I've found that the companion apps for several of the receivers display these, for example [Eos Tools Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.eos_gnss.eostoolspro&hl=en) displays them when used with the [Arrow 200 receiver](http://www.eos-gnss.com/arrow-200/).

I've also found a [PhD thesis](http://eprints.nottingham.ac.uk/13939/2/LKB_PhD_Thesis.pdf) which contains some equations, but I'm having trouble understanding how to abstract them into a generic formula. However, it looks like PDOP is involve, so I would assume I need to parse the GSA message in addition to the GST.

Where can I find the relevant formulas or how to calculate these values?

Comment: OP, please confirm that I've expanded out VRMS, HRMS and 3DRMS correctly. Thanks.

Comment: @mkennedy, yes the definitions look correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've arrived at the following solutions based on the formuale in [this page](http://www.navipedia.net/index.php/Positioning_Error):

[image]

My original calculation of the 3DRMS was wrong because the [RMS](http://www.mathwords.com/r/root_mean_square.htm) should take the [arithmetic mean](http://www.mathwords.com/a/arithmetic_mean.htm) of the squares.

My conclusion is that :

- VRMS is actually another term for the 1-sigma altitude error which is already present in the GST message field 8
- HRMS is 2-sigma horizontal RMS, derived from the latitude and longitude sigmas in fields 6 & 7 of the GST message.

In pseudo-code:

```
LatErr = GST[6]
LonErr = GST[7]
AltErr = GST[8]

VRMS = AltErr
HRMS = 2* Math.sqrt(((Math.pow(LatErr, 2) + Math.pow(LonErr, 2))/2));
3DRMS = 3* Math.sqrt(((Math.pow(LatErr, 2) + Math.pow(LonErr, 2))/2));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think pseudo code should be like below

```
    HRMS = 2* Math.sqrt(0.5*((Math.pow(LatErr, 2) + Math.pow(LonErr, 2))/2));

    3DRMS = 3* Math.sqrt(0.5*((Math.pow(LatErr, 2) + Math.pow(LonErr, 2))/2));
```